# Fullcalendar Custom Views via JS classes destroy throws errors

Tags: angularjs, fullcalendar, fullcalendar-scheduler, fullcalendar-3

I have implemented Fullcalendar Custom View by referring document [Custom Views via JS classes](https://fullcalendar.io/docs/custom-view-with-js). It seems to worki fine, but the **`destroy`** method throws an error: `View.prototype.destroy.apply is not function`.

I have used the below code:

```
var FC = $.fullCalendar;
var View = FC.View;
var BlankView;

BlankView = View.extend({
    initialize: function() {
       // View.prototype.initialize.apply(this, arguments);
    },
    setHeight: function(height, isAuto) {
    },
    render: function () {
        this.title = this.title || 'TestView';
        if (this.el[0].children.length === 0) this.el.addClass('fc-basic-view').html(this.renderHtml());
    },
    destroyEvents: function() {
        // responsible for undoing everything in renderEvents
    },
    destroy: function() {
         View.prototype.destroy.apply(this, arguments);
    },
    renderHtml: function () {
        this.el.html('<div></div>');
    },



});

FC.views.blank = BlankView;
```

Any clues to achieve the `destroy` method in custom views?

Comment: what error, exactly?

Comment: View.prototype.destroy.apply is not function

Comment: @Robert Could you please setup [mcve](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)? It is really hard to understand the root cause of your issue just only with the code snippet provided in the question.